# How can I write my source API documentation in Angular projects, so that it generates HTML content that can be accessed offline as well

Tags: angularjs, jsdoc

I am writing an angularjs based project

and I wish to add source documentation something like Java Docs to the source. I have seen JSDOC and DGENI jsDOC being easier option but still lacks the comprehensive support for Angular and DGeni being a bit difficult to comprehend.

Are there any good information materials I can refer to?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Ok, point noted. But still got no answers to the post. :)

Answer (score 0):

Viewing the repository: https://github.com/petebacondarwin/dgeni-angular
This is an example for a angularjs project was done by the creator of Dgeni.

The **src** directory contains the commented sources of your project and the **docs** directory contains configuration for Dgeni.

Forresst

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.